# Delphi anonymous methods - pro and cons. Good practices when using closures(anonymus methods) in Delphi

Tags: delphi, closures, anonymous-methods

I have a colleague in my team which is extensively using closures in our projects developed in Delphi. Personal, I don't like this because is making code harder to read and I believe that closures should be used ONLY when you need them.

In the other hand I've read [Can someone explain Anonymous methods to me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256146/can-someone-explain-anonymous-methods-to-me) and other links related to this, and I'm taking into account that maybe I'm wrong, so I'm asking you to give me some examples when is better to use closures instead of a 'old-fashion' approach (not using closures).

Comment: The main issue is variable capture and the lifetime changes that produces. There can be some rather unexpected effects, especially when you have multiple anonymous methods defined within the same scope that share variable capture. I'd generally avoid using anonymous methods unless they make the code clearer and simpler.

Comment: Anonymous methods belong to functional programming paradigm. They are rather alien in imperative Delphi environment and have very limited value compared with functional languages.

Comment: See OmniThreadLibrary for example - I like the way Gabriel uses closures there...

Comment: Lambdae were added to Delphi only because "everybody have them, and we dont" and there was no Heilsberg to talks some sense into them. It is againt Pascal paradigm and naturally resulted in severe language uglyfication (along with violation basic Pascal parenhesis syntax too)

Comment: Gabriel's code is a good example of modern-smart-guy who uses all the new features, but who is very careful, for example, and who uses unit tests, and makes low level code you can trust.

Comment: I disagree strongly with Serg. I know Python and Delphi, and I recognize that the longer syntax in Delphi is the necessary side-effect of strong typing. Dynamic typing and lambdas is a nice match, but lambdas/closures are valuable in a strongly typed language, such as C++, and in Pascal, as it is in Python.  Along with traits (implemented with interfaces), there are in fact, some powerful ways in which a static type system benefits from Lambdas even more than in Python, since in python you could do a lot of the lambda trickery stuff just using dynamic language hacks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe that this question calls for a very subjective judgement. I am an old-school delphi developer, and inclined to agree with you. Not only do closures add certain risks (as David H points out in comments) they also reduce readability for all classically trained Delphi developers.   So why were they added to the language at all?  In Delphi XE, the syntax-formatting function and closures weren't working well together, for example, and this increased my mistrust of closures;  How much stuff gets added to the Delphi compiler, that the IDE hasn't been fully upgraded to support?  You know you're a cranky old timer when you admit publically that you would have been happy if the Delphi language was frozen at the Delphi 7 level and never improved again.  But Delphi is a living, powerful, evolving syntax.  And that's a good thing. Repeat that to yourself when you find the old-crank taking over. Give it a try.

I can think of at least ten places where Anonymous methods really make sense and thus, reasons why you should use them, notwithstanding my earlier comment that I mistrust them.  I will only point out the two that I have decided to personally use, and the limits that I place on myself when I use them:

1. Sort methods in container classes in the Generics.Collections accept an anonymous method so that you can easily provide a sorting bit of logic without having to write a regular (non-anonymous) function that matches the same signature that the sort method expects. The new generics syntax fits hand in hand with this style, and though it looks alien to you at first, it grows on you and becomes if not exactly really nice to use, at least more convenient than the alternatives.
2. TThread methods like Synchronize are overloaded, and in addition to supporting a single TThreadMethod as a parameter `Thread.Synchronize(aClassMethodWithoutParameters)`, it has always been a source of pain to me, to get the parameters into that synchronize method. now you can use a closure (anonymous method), and pass the parameters in.

Limits that I recommend in writing anonymous methods:

A. I have a personal rule of thumb of only ONE closure per function, and whenever there is more than one, refactor out that bit of code to its own method.  This keeps the cyclomatic complexity of your "methods" from going insane.

B. Also, inside each closure, I prefer to have only a single method invocation, and its parameters, and if I end up writing giant blocks of code, I rewrite those to be methods. Closures are for variable capture, not a carte-blanche for writing endlessly-twisted spaghetti code.

Sample sort:

```
 var     
   aContainer:TList<TPair<String, Integer>>;  
 begin   
  aContainer.Sort(    
    TMyComparer.Construct(
      function (const L, R: TPair<String, Integer>): integer
      begin
        result := SysUtils.CompareStr(L.Key,R.Key);
      end ) {Construct end}   );  {aContainer.Sort end}  
 end;
```

Update: one comment points to "language uglification", I believe that the uglification refers to the difference between having to write:

```
  x.Sort(     
    TMyComparer.Construct(
      function (const L, R: TPair<String, Integer>): integer
      begin
        result := SysUtils.CompareStr(L.Key,R.Key);
      end )   );
```

Instead of, the following hypothetical duck-typed (or should I have said inferred types) syntax that I just invented here for comparison:

```
  x.Sort( lambda( [L,R], [ SysUtils.CompareStr(L.Key,R.Key) ] ) )
```

Some other languages like Smalltalk, and Python can write lambdas more compactly because they are dynamically typed. The need for an IComparer, for example, as the type passed to a Sort() method in a container, is an example of complexity caused by the interface-flavor that strongly typed languages with generics have to follow in order to implement traits like ordering, required for sortability.   I don't think there was a nice way to do this. Personally I hate seeing procedure, begin and end  keywords inside a function invocation parenthesis, but I don't see what else could reasonably have been done.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, (1) is merely a "shorthand" argument, maybe in combination with the fact that it allows type aggregates as parameter without first defining it separately (something which standard Pascal did support btw). But the allowing of aggregates of types in param declarations could be allowed for normal procedures/methods too?

Comment: Not exactly shorthand, although yes, it's shorter.  More that the conditional you write or function comparison you write is localized inside the calling context instead of declared elsewhere (outside the procedure scope, as its own procedure). Not only does this allow  capture of parameters, if you will forgive the ugly procedure begin end part of the lambda, it's really quite readable.  And if you wanted to allow invocation of thread-procedures-with-arbiratrary-params you'd be making 100+ versions of `TThread.Synchronize( method:TIntStringCharDoubleIntStrCharMethod );`

Comment: "can write lambdas more compactly because they are dynamically typed" You don't need dynamic typing for that. It's harder to write the compiler for this in a statically typed language. But look how C# supports type inference in these scenarios.

Comment: as I said, type inference (duck typing) would require some intelligence in the compiler that the delphi compiler infrastructure lacks.  C# is hardly a purely statically typed language, since it's a CLR-driven code-dom powered dynamic language environment that also has static typing, which at this point, is basically syntactic sugar.  What I mean, is that you can run Python on .net (iron python) and so, .net is fully dynamically typed now, and C# is merely one of several syntax flavors available on top.

Comment: @WarrenP I disagree. Type inference is not duck typing. In duck typing the only concern is with capabilities, not names. Like interfaces, it only cares if the object has methods X, Y, and Z, not with type. Type inference employs the Hindley–Milner algorithm to deduce the static type from the way the variable is used. The most statically typed language can use H-M and there's no need to support duck typing at all. C# is statically typed. It's not "sugar". SWIG wraps C++ for Python but C++ isn't dynamic. Python has Qt bindings although Qt is written in C++.

Comment: I can implement anything in anything. What's your point?  Hindley-Milner, etc etc.  My truck can become an Orange  Tree if I bolt an Orange tree on it.   (That's how I feel about C++ by the way, you can bolt a nice language onto it, it's just a shame nobody made the language you bolt on the actual language.)  ANyways, Delphi requires types to be spelled out and does not provide a compact type inference system, and neither you nor I can add it. The fact that the authors of the compiler could add it some day is beside the point.